# What does it mean when you pass Class<? extends Activity>

Tags: android, class, parameters, constructor

Looking at a sample code there is a class constructor that one of the parameters being passed. What does the question mark mean.

Comment: at compile time it means that you have to pass class that is extending Activity class ... but at runtime it means nothing since java's generics are ...(add some f-words here), no the same as in C#

Comment: you can pass `AnyActivity.class`